# How to remove part of a url?

Tags: php, url, relative-path

Trying to turn this:

```
href="/wp-content/themes/tray/img/celebrity_photos/photo.jpg"
```

into:

```
href="/img/celebrity_photos/photo.jpg"
```

So I'm simply trying to *remove* `/wp-content/themes/tray/` from the url.

Here's the plug in's PHP code that builds a variable for each anchor path:

```
$this->imageURL = '/' . $this->path . '/' . $this->filename;
```

So I'd like to say:

```
$this->imageURL = '/' . $this->path -/wp-content/themes/tray/ . '/' . $this->filename;
```

PHP `substr()`? `strpos()`?

Comment: `preg_replace` is about the worst possible choice for such a simple task.

Comment: @Jon - second worst.  I think `ltrim()` might be the worst.  :-)

Comment: Why am I the only thinking it's as simple as `str_replace`? You guys really got me wondering whether I'm getting what the OP really needs...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: Your solution will be just as good in practice; it's just a little more liberal with what it replaces than it needs to be.

Comment: @Jon Oh, how I love it when I end up discussing PHP code in english... with greeks... lol :-)

Comment: Thanks Jon , ghoti and  Dr.Kameleon for the clarification .... Read the documentation clearly now ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that:

```
$this->imageURL = '/' . $this->path . '/' . $this->filename;
$remove = "/wp-content/themes/tray";
```

This is how to remove a known prefix, if it exists:

```
if (strpos($this->imageURL, $remove) === 0) {
    $this->imageURL = substr($this->imageURL, strlen($remove));
}
```

If you are *certain* that it always exists then you can also lose the `if` condition.

Answer (score 2):

This is one option:

```
$h="/wp-content/themes/tray/img/celebrity_photos/photo-on-4-6-12-at-3-23-pm.jpg";

$prefix="/wp-content/themes/tray/";

print str_replace($prefix, "/", $h, 1);
```

It suffers from one major flaw, which is that it doesn't anchor itself to the left-hand-side of `$h`.  To do this, you'd either need to use a regular expression (which is heavier on processing) or wrap this in something that detects the position of your prefix before running the `str_replace()`.

```
$h="/wp-content/themes/tray/img/celebrity_photos/photo-on-4-6-12-at-3-23-pm.jpg";

$prefix="/wp-content/themes/tray/";

if (strpos(" ".$h, $prefix) == 1)
  $result = str_replace($prefix, "/", $h, 1);
else
  $result = $h;

print $result;
```

Note this important element: the prefix **ends** in a slash.  You don't want to match other themes like "trayn" or "traypse".  Beware writing things for just your specific use case.  Always try to figure out how code might break, and program around problematic hypothetical use cases.

Comment: Isn't that `== 1` check a bug? `strpos` would actually be expected to return `0` there. Also, what if `$prefix` exists in multiple places in the url?

Comment: Wups, right you are.  Thanks for pointing that out.  `strpos()`'s zero-offset always gets me.  :-P  I've prepended a space to avoid comparing both `===TRUE` and `==0`.  Also, I've handled the risk of `$prefix` later in the line by adding a `$count` to `str_replace()`.

Comment: OTOH, I guess `if (strpos($h, $prefix) === 0)` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$href = str_replace("/wp-content/themes/tray","",$href);
```

Or in your specific case, something like this :

```
$this->imageURL = '/' . str_replace("/wp-content/themes/tray/","",$this->path) . '/' . $this->filename;
```

Comment: I won't downvote this, but I do think the first suggestion here suffers from the thing ghoti warned about, regarding the trailing slash.